# Count number of sessions and email as a body

Tags: shell-script

I want to create a script to achieve followings :

1.login to Essbase MaxL

```
essmsh -l admin password on localhost;
```

2.Count the number of lines in the output of command display session all;

```
display session all; | wc -l  < /filepath/filename.ext
```

3.Email the the counted number of lines to a set of recipients as email-body like below :

**Total number of Sessions = bla-number**

```
display session all; | wc -l   > file.tmp
mailx -s "Subject" emailaddresses < file.tmp
rm file.tmp
```

how we can get all 3 through a single script ?

**EDIT**

Based on Casey's answer, the single script now I have :

```
#!/bin/bash

#Maxl zone starts.....
essmsh -l admin password -s localhost -i << EOF

spool on to 'output.txt';
display session all;
spool off;

EOF
#Maxl zone ends.....

wc -l output.txt  > file.tmp 

mailx -s "Subject" emailaddresses < file.tmp
rm file.tmp
```

Comment: Which shell are you using? `; |` is not valid Bash syntax to separate commands.

Comment: @10bo..actually in `display session all; | wc -l < /filepath/filename.ext`..command `display session all;` is a essmsh command while `wc -l < /filepath/filename.ext` is a normal shell command which doesn't seem to be working in essmsh .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `essmsh` is in your path, and assuming the commands you listed are valid essmsh shell commands (I'm not familiar), this script should get you started.

```
#!/bin/bash

essmsh -i << EOF
# PUT COMMANDS TO essmsh HERE
EOF

mailx -s "Subject" emailaddresses < file.tmp
rm file.tmp
```

From the man page, the `-i` flag tells `essmsh` to use commands piped in from stdin.  The `<< EOF ... EOF` construct causes everything in between the EOFs to be sent to the program via stdin.  After the EOF, `essmsh` should exit and the rest of your commands are normal shell commands.

Comment: Casay..actually in `display session all; | wc -l  < /filepath/filename.ext`..only `display session all;` is a essmsh command (which is working) while `wc -l  < /filepath/filename.ext` is a normal shell command which doesn't seem to be working in essmsh . I am not getting how i can Count the number of lines in or out of essmsh ?..meanwhile I am checking any solution in MaxL manuals.

Comment: I would suggest then storing the output of essmsh (redirecting to a file or pipe or storing in a shell variable) and do post-processing on that output.

Comment: yeah..got the way (pls see EDIT)....I'll test it and will let you know the result :)

Comment: Looks like you'll just need to add the line to login to the server to your essmsh command and it'll do what you want.

Comment: oh..yes..added..!:)